# Canonical choice of inverse system for profinite set.

Tags: general-topology, profinite-groups

Let $X$ be a profinite set - an inverse limit $\varprojlim X_i$. How can one prove that then $X=\varprojlim Y_i$, where $Y_i$ is finite quotient spaces of $X$? I may prove it if $X$ is topological group, since $\varprojlim$ is left-exact, $X=\varprojlim X/K_i=\varprojlim Y_i$ where $K_i$ is kernel of $X \to X_i$. But there aren't kernels in topological case.

Comment: Do you really mean profinite sets, or profinite spaces?

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg I mean topological spaces, which are inverse limits of finite sets with discrete topology. According to http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/profinite+space it's profinite sets.